# SAP's Kapsel plugin supports only OData. What about JSON?

Tags: json, cordova, odata, sapui5, sencha-touch

I'm starting a hybrid application based in Cordova. A requirement includes to be working with the offline Kapsel plugin provide by SAP, but I have been looking this plugin support only OData. Does it mean I cannot work with JSON responses? Or maybe it's independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData and Json are two unrelated technologies. OData is a protocol, Json is a format.
You can very well connect to an OData service and have it return data in a Json format.